# K2 Getting values from SQL Server table using store procedure for the filtered items

Tags: sql-query

new to K2 using store procedure

I have four drop down controls in the smartform and i have a button called search.

In the drop down controls i am going to select values in the each dropdowns and click search button.

Based on the selected value in the dropdown i have to pass the selected value as a query to SQL table and get the record from the table and show in the gridview using Store Procedure.

****** All the records created /stored in the SQL Table.

Please Kindly help on this.

And let me know if any other way to achieve the above functionality.

Thanks in advance.